# Captive - runtime flash builder running app error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder, apk

Im using flash builder 4.6 but have tried on 4.7 too using the captive runtime apk creation method.(I want air to install with my app not have a third party install) but its not working.
I am testing this with a hello world app and I keep getting the message "unfortunately, (myappname) has stopped" I don't know how when this is a simple app. Ive looked at tutorials and updated the airSDK any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Styles I think not sure -->
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home"> 
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Basic structure of the app page -->

        <!-- Label on the screen -->
<!-- Label onn the screen -->
        <s:Label text="HelloWorld"/>
</s:View> 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">

<!-- Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File Template.

    Specifies parameters for identifying, installing, and launching AIR applications.

    xmlns - The Adobe AIR namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1
            The last segment of the namespace specifies the version 
            of the AIR runtime required for this application to run.

    minimumPatchLevel - The minimum patch level of the AIR runtime required to run 
            the application. Optional.
-->

    <!-- A universally unique application identifier. Must be unique across all AIR applications.
    Using a reverse DNS-style name as the id is recommended. (Eg. com.example.ExampleApplication.) Required. -->
    <id>app</id>

    <!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
    <filename>app</filename>

    <!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. 
    May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <name>app</name>

    <!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. 
    Values can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value.
    An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
    <versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>

    <!-- A string value (such as "v1", "2.5", or "Alpha 1") that represents the version of the application, as it should be shown to users. Optional. -->
    <!-- <versionLabel></versionLabel> -->

    <!-- Description, displayed in the AIR application installer.
    May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <!-- <description></description> -->

    <!-- Copyright information. Optional -->
    <!-- <copyright></copyright> -->

    <!-- Publisher ID. Used if you're updating an application created prior to 1.5.3 -->
    <!-- <publisherID></publisherID> -->

    <!-- Settings for the application's initial window. Required. -->
    <initialWindow>
        <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
        <!-- Note: In Flash Builder, the SWF reference is set automatically. -->
        <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>

        <!-- The title of the main window. Optional. -->
        <!-- <title></title> -->

        <!-- The type of system chrome to use (either "standard" or "none"). Optional. Default standard. -->
        <!-- <systemChrome></systemChrome> -->

        <!-- Whether the window is transparent. Only applicable when systemChrome is none. Optional. Default false. -->
        <!-- <transparent></transparent> -->

        <!-- Whether the window is initially visible. Optional. Default false. -->
        <!-- <visible></visible> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can minimize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <minimizable></minimizable> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can maximize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <maximizable></maximizable> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <resizable></resizable> -->

        <!-- The window's initial width in pixels. Optional. -->
        <!-- <width></width> -->

        <!-- The window's initial height in pixels. Optional. -->
        <!-- <height></height> -->

        <!-- The window's initial x position. Optional. -->
        <!-- <x></x> -->

        <!-- The window's initial y position. Optional. -->
        <!-- <y></y> -->

        <!-- The window's minimum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "400 200". Optional. -->
        <!-- <minSize></minSize> -->

        <!-- The window's initial maximum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "1600 1200". Optional. -->
        <!-- <maxSize></maxSize> -->

        <!-- The initial aspect ratio of the app when launched (either "portrait" or "landscape"). Optional. Mobile only. Default is the natural orientation of the device -->

        <!-- <aspectRatio></aspectRatio> -->

        <!-- Whether the app will begin auto-orienting on launch. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

        <!-- <autoOrients></autoOrients> -->

        <!-- Whether the app launches in full screen. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

        <!-- <fullScreen></fullScreen> -->

        <!-- The render mode for the app (either auto, cpu, gpu, or direct). Optional. Default auto -->

        <!-- <renderMode></renderMode> -->

        <!-- Whether or not to pan when a soft keyboard is raised or lowered (either "pan" or "none").  Optional.  Defaults "pan." -->
        <!-- <softKeyboardBehavior></softKeyboardBehavior> -->
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>
    </initialWindow>

    <!-- We recommend omitting the supportedProfiles element, -->
    <!-- which in turn permits your application to be deployed to all -->
    <!-- devices supported by AIR. If you wish to restrict deployment -->
    <!-- (i.e., to only mobile devices) then add this element and list -->
    <!-- only the profiles which your application does support. -->
    <!-- <supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice extendedMobileDevice</supportedProfiles> -->

    <!-- The subpath of the standard default installation location to use. Optional. -->
    <!-- <installFolder></installFolder> -->

    <!-- The subpath of the Programs menu to use. (Ignored on operating systems without a Programs menu.) Optional. -->
    <!-- <programMenuFolder></programMenuFolder> -->

    <!-- The icon the system uses for the application. For at least one resolution,
    specify the path to a PNG file included in the AIR package. Optional. -->
    <!-- <icon>
        <image16x16></image16x16>
        <image32x32></image32x32>
        <image36x36></image36x36>
        <image48x48></image48x48>
        <image57x57></image57x57>
        <image72x72></image72x72>
        <image114x114></image114x114>
        <image128x128></image128x128>
    </icon> -->

    <!-- Whether the application handles the update when a user double-clicks an update version
    of the AIR file (true), or the default AIR application installer handles the update (false).
    Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <customUpdateUI></customUpdateUI> -->

    <!-- Whether the application can be launched when the user clicks a link in a web browser.
    Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <allowBrowserInvocation></allowBrowserInvocation> -->

    <!-- Listing of file types for which the application can register. Optional. -->
    <!-- <fileTypes> -->

        <!-- Defines one file type. Optional. -->
        <!-- <fileType> -->

            <!-- The name that the system displays for the registered file type. Required. -->
            <!-- <name></name> -->

            <!-- The extension to register. Required. -->
            <!-- <extension></extension> -->

            <!-- The description of the file type. Optional. -->
            <!-- <description></description> -->

            <!-- The MIME content type. -->
            <!-- <contentType></contentType> -->

            <!-- The icon to display for the file type. Optional. -->
            <!-- <icon>
                <image16x16></image16x16>
                <image32x32></image32x32>
                <image48x48></image48x48>
                <image128x128></image128x128>
            </icon> -->

        <!-- </fileType> -->
    <!-- </fileTypes> -->

    <!-- iOS specific capabilities -->
    <!-- <iPhone> -->
        <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Info.plist -->
        <!-- <InfoAdditions>
            <![CDATA[
                <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
                <array>
                    <string>1</string>
                    <string>2</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <string>YES</string>
            ]]>
        </InfoAdditions> -->
        <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Entitlements.plist -->
        <!-- <Entitlements>
            <![CDATA[
                <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
                <array>
                    <string></string>
                    <string></string>
                </array>
            ]]>
        </Entitlements> -->
    <!-- Display Resolution for the app (either "standard" or "high"). Optional. Default "standard" -->
    <!-- <requestedDisplayResolution></requestedDisplayResolution> -->
    <!-- </iPhone> -->

    <!-- Specify Android specific tags that get passed to AndroidManifest.xml file. -->
    <!--<android> -->
    <!--    <manifestAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
                <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
                <application android:enabled="true">
                    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                </application>
            </manifest>
        ]]>
        </manifestAdditions> -->
        <!-- Color depth for the app (either "32bit" or "16bit"). Optional. Default 16bit before namespace 3.0, 32bit after -->
        <!-- <colorDepth></colorDepth> -->
    <!-- </android> -->
    <!-- End of the schema for adding the android specific tags in AndroidManifest.xml file -->

<android>
        <colorDepth>16bit</colorDepth>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <!--See the Adobe AIR documentation for more information about setting Google Android permissions-->
                <!--Removing the permission android.permission.INTERNET will have the side effect
        of preventing you from debugging your application on your device-->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>-->
                <!--The DISABLE_KEYGUARD and WAKE_LOCK permissions should be toggled together
        in order to access AIR's SystemIdleMode APIs-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>-->
                <!--The ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions should be toggled
        together in order to use AIR's NetworkInfo APIs-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>-->

                <!--See the Adobe AIR documentation for more information about setting Google Android permissions-->
                <!--Removing the permission android.permission.INTERNET will have the side effect of preventing you from debugging your application on your device-->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

                <!--The DISABLE_KEYGUARD and WAKE_LOCK permissions should be toggled together in order to access AIR's SystemIdleMode APIs-->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

                <!--The ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions should be toggled together in order to use AIR's NetworkInfo APIs-->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

            </manifest>

        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
        ]]></InfoAdditions>
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone>
</application>
```

The AIRSDK version says 13.0 on the readme so I assume thats the one i am using

Comment: I would suggest installing something like [LogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.interdenshi.android.Logcat) on your device you you can see the event log, this might help diagnose the problem

Comment: tried it but i cant even get an app to start running to get logs(traces in this case)

Comment: What version(s) of the AIR SDK are you using? Could you provide the app.xml? What device and what version of Android are you running?

Comment: @JoshJanusch Question has been updated! thanks fo the help